# Stop automatic sort from happening?

Tags: apache-flex, datagrid

I got a dataGrid, but I'd like it to not automatically sort the data when first is loaded with data, is there any way to do it?.

(I still want to order the data, but only when I click the column, and not by default at the start)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Flex Datagrids do not sort the dataProvider by default. They just show the information in the same order as it is in the dataprovider. 
However, maybe your dataprovider has a sort applied. 
What dataprovider are you using? Is it an ArrayCollection?

Can you attach some code so I can see what's happening? Especially it would be useful if you copy&paste your Datagrid declaration and the code where you declare and fill your dataprovider.

Comment: I just found out that I was sorting the ArrayCollection I was providing as data source. I thought it was a default behavior of the DataGrid component, it wasn't in the end.